# complete RSS truncated feeds

Tags: scripting, php, rss-aggregator

I am looking for a way to locally complete RSS truncated feeds.

I was using for years wizardrss[dont click]com (it’s now a squated) witch was an online service who do the stuff. But it turn off since ~3years and I didn’t see it…

Anyway, for the moment I find an online service alternative [FiveFilters](http://fivefilters.org/content-only/) but it still a web service. So I search a way to do it locally.

It seams it’s not really a documentation about it. So the only think I find is [this](https://philippe.scoffoni.net/logiciel-completer-flux-rss-tronques/) [french only :/] article who cite tree tools:

- [Simplepie](http://simplepie.org/): Allow RSS feed parsing
- [Readability](http://lab.arc90.com/2009/03/02/readability/): Allow the reading of the web version of an RSS article
- Feedwriter [No link]: Allow the complete new feed generation.

But this article didn’t explain at all how to configure each tool, and the Readability’s link seams broken.

So, is there a solution to complete RSS truncated feeds? By using this tree tools, or other way?

Comment: Do you have to use a web service/page? Why not use a library in python or java?

Comment: yes, I can absolutely use it. Anyway, the  only constraint is to be local.